# prototype.function vs this.function with a twist

Tags: javascript

Old question, asked and answered many times, but with a bit of a twist. First the prototype version:

```
someA = function() {
    this.val = 'a';
}
someA.prototype.getVal = function() {
    return this.val;
}
```

Now the other version:

```
someA = function() {
    this.val = 'a';
    this.getVal = function() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say the getVal() function is **HUGE**, and you'll be creating thousands of objects of someA, but for whatever reason, you wanted to use the this.getVal version?  What if we wrote it this way:

```
someA =function() {
    this.val = 'a';
    this.getVal = this._getVal;
}
someA.prototype._getVal = function() {
    return this.val;
}
```

Doing it this way, would you essentially have the advantages of both?

p.s. On a completely different (but still somewhat related) topic, how does one add the questions and comments *inside* the question or one of the answers?

**Edited:** changed all occurances of `return val` to `return this.val` -- dumb mistake ;-)

Comment: I suppose you want to make `val` private. As of now, `val` is still public. There are also some errors in your code. You cannot reference `this.val` with just `val`.

Comment: this is a comment. just click on "add Comment" below this. same thing on answers

Comment: @bennedich that's what I get for posting a question at 3am. Changed the code to return `this.val`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just aliasing the prototyped function, there is no benefit. A function defined elsewhere does not become aware of any variables when you assign it to something. It doesn't suddenly have `val` in its scope.

A function can however have different object context for each invocation regardless of where the function was defined. This is allows for true function re-use for different objects and one doesn't need to hold everything in huge chains of closures and recreate them for each object.

You can try to run the code to see that it doesn't work:

```
someA =function() {
    var val = 'a';
    this.getVal = this._getVal;
}
someA.prototype._getVal = function() {
    return val; //This will throw reference error because the `val` is not
                //known here.
}
```

Comment: `_getVal` *should* have returned `this.val`. My mistake. Re-use is, of course, my intent in this discussion.

Comment: @JohnFrickson in that case there is absolutely no difference. You will just add a redundant alias. It will work normally without the assignment, it will work normally with the assignment. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no point in doing this IMO.

Some people might argue that the prototype version will save you memory and give you slightly better performance. It might be true, probably not enough to make a significant difference although you could try setting up a test at jsPerf and see what results you get.

There's of course a difference between the two. The prototype will only create one instance of the property or method and the constructor will create as many as instances of the object there are.

I'd say, just go with whatever makes sense to you or combine both. If you're really concerned about performance then use the constructor to add properties that might change or that must be unique for each instance, and use the prototype to create your public method that works with all instances.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the example below works, is that the `getVal` function is in a closure, keeping in scope all of the variables in scope in the outer function, therefore as a result of creating an instance of running `someA` gives you an object with a method `getVal` that can access the value of `val`.

```
var someA = function() {
  var val = 'a';
  this.getVal = function() {
    return val;
  }
};
```

If you are exposing val as a member variable (ie: `this.val = 'a';`) then you would need the `getVal` method to also return the member variable version, and not just `return val;`.

```
var someA = function() {}
someA.prototype = {
  val: 'a',
  getVal: function() {
    return this.val;
  }
};
```

Using the prototype means that this is functionally identical to:

```
var someA = function() {
  this.val = 'a';
  this.getVal = function() {
    return this.val;
  }
}
```

but has significant performance gains as there is only ever one instance of the getVal function. You can however make use of a single function instance with multiple references by rewriting it to:

```
var _getVal = function() {
  return this.val;
};
var someA = function() {
  this.val = 'a';
  this.getVal = _getVal;
}
```